# Django key error "request" when using inlineformset

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, inline-formset

I created a Class Based(CreateView) with in inlineformset. I need to pass the `request.user` to the form to enable a filter function on one of the form fields. I however get a `Key Error: request` on the line:
`self.request = kwargs.pop('request')` in the `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):` of the form. Assistance will be appreciated.
Tips on my programming also welcome.

models.py:

```
class ttransactions(models.Model):
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=tx_choices)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default='Description')
    transaction_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today, db_index=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(tcompany, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_index=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.description


class ttransaction_lines(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(ttransactions, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    sequence = models.IntegerField()
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=debit_credit)
    ledger_account = models.ForeignKey(tledger_account, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_index=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    posted = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class TransactionLinesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ttransaction_lines
        fields = ['transaction_type', 'ledger_account', 'amount']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super(TransactionLinesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        current_company = user.current_company
        self.fields['ledger_account'].queryset = tledger_account.objects.filter(
            company=current_company)

TransactionLineFormset = inlineformset_factory(ttransactions,
                                               ttransaction_lines,
                                               # fields=['transaction_type', 'ledger_account', 'amount'] ,
                                               form=TransactionLinesForm,
                                               can_order=True, can_delete=True)
```

views.py:

```
class JournalCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
template_name = 'accounting/journal.html'
model = ttransactions
transaction_lines_form = TransactionLineFormset
form_class = TransactionsForm
success_url = '/accounting/transaction_list'

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(JournalCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['request'] = self.request
    return kwargs

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    transaction_lines_form = TransactionLineFormset()
    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form, transaction_lines_form=transaction_lines_form))

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    extra_forms = 1
    if 'additems' in request.POST and request.POST['additems'] == 'true':
        formset_dictionary_copy = self.request.POST.copy()
        formset_dictionary_copy['form-TOTAL_FORMS'] = \
            int(formset_dictionary_copy['form-TOTAL_FORMS']) + extra_forms
        transaction_lines_form = TransactionLinesFormSet(formset_dictionary_copy)
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  transaction_lines_form=transaction_lines_form))

    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)

    transaction_lines_form = TransactionLineFormset(self.request.POST)
    if (form.is_valid() and transaction_lines_form.is_valid()):
        return self.form_valid(form, transaction_lines_form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form, transaction_lines_form)

def form_valid(self, form, transaction_lines_form):
    form.instance.company = self.request.user.current_company
    self.object = form.save()

    sequence = 1
    for line in transaction_lines_form:
        line.instance.sequence = sequence
        sequence += 1

    transaction_lines_form.instance = self.object
    transaction_lines_form.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)

def form_invalid(self, form, transaction_lines_form):
    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form,
                              transaction_lines_form=transaction_lines_form))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form may be initialized at multiple places. It is difficult to find where the error happened without seeing the Traceback.

So, it is better to keep the filtering logic in the view rather than passing 'request' to form. Remove `__init__` method in form and try the below code in the view

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    transaction_lines_form = TransactionLineFormset()
    transaction_lines_form.form.base_fields['ledger_account'].queryset = \
        tledger_account.objects.filter(company=request.user.current_company)

    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form, transaction_lines_form=transaction_lines_form))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately with trying different options I send the incorrect views.py version. I corrected it on the question. The problem is the ledger account is on the transaction lines form. When I change the code as you suggested on the transaction lines I get the error: ttransaction_linesFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'fields'. Can you please help again. Sorry about the incorrect data.

Comment: I have edited the answer for filtering transaction_lines_form queryset. Please try.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I now get an error: type object 'ttransaction_linesForm' has no attribute 'basefields'. Should I create a BaseModelFormSet? If so, can you give advice on that as well.

Comment: Sorry. It was supposed to be `base_fields`. Edited in Answer.