# How can I get the current user when dealing with a Django InlineFormset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I've spent the better part of today looking for this answer.  Long story short I'm trying to figure out how to get the current user ID that is logged in so that I can dynamically query a field and show the options available to them based on their ID.  This all works well except for the part when I need their ID.  I need it when they open the view, not at form save time.

Here is an example of my code...

Forms.py

```
LineItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ParentModel, ChildModel, extra=1, fields=['line_item_cost_center','line_item_description','line_item_vendor'])

class LineItemFormSet(LineItemFormSet,BaseInlineFormSet):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    print(self.user)
    super(LineItemFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def add_fields(self, form, index):
    super(LineItemFormSet,self).add_fields(form,index)
    form.fields['line_item_description'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'budget2'
    form.fields['line_item_description'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Required'
    qs1 = Vendor.objects.exclude(Q(is_active=False)).distinct()
    form.fields['line_item_vendor'].queryset = qs1
```

The above works just fine....However, I am trying to get the current user so that I can do something like..

```
Vendor.objects.filter(Q(admin_access=user)).exclude(is_active=False).distinct()
```

I have tried various incarnations of subclassing BaseInlineFormset....But to no avail.

I tried something like...

```
class BaseFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    
    self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)  
    super(BaseFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then I did something like...

```
LineItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ParentEntity, ChildEntity, formset=BaseFormSet, form=ChildForm, extra=1)

formset = LineItemFormSet(form_kwargs={'request': request})
```

And then I kept getting an error that says that request is not found.

My View looks like...

```
class CreateLineItemView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = NewLineItem
    form_class = CreateLineItemForm
    template_name = 'create_line_item.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        budget_line_item_form = CreateLineItemFormSet()
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  line_item_form=line_item_form,
                                  context=context,
                                  ))

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(CreateLineItemView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Any ideas on how I can get the current user so that I can leverage with my queryset would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `formset = LineItemFormSet(request=request)` otherwise you'll have to get the request from `form_kwargs`

Comment: @BrianDestura Thanks for the feedback.  I tried your suggestion and it still keeps saying request is not defined.

Comment: Can you share the latest code you've tried?

Comment: @BrianDestura I literally am using the code outlined above and changed the problematic line as you suggested and that's the error message I'm getting.

Comment: formset = LineItemFormSet(request=request)

Comment: Sorry my suggestions are wrong. Let me check a bit closer

Answer (score 1):

And the long story in short. Just use the session variable when the user logs in.

```
def login(request):
  #your code here
  request.session['userID']=the_user_id
  .
  .
  #rest of your code
```

Now you can use this id in any view or template. Like

**#in any other view**

```
def myview(request):
  user_id=request.session['userID']
  #rest of your code
```

**#in template**

You can directly use the userID in templates like

```
{{request.session.userID}}
```

**OR**

you can make a global variable in DOM for javascript use

```
<script>
window.userID={{request.session.userID}};
//use userID variable anywhere in DOM
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is the answer....based on this SO.  [Django key error "request" when using inlineformset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65411183/django-key-error-request-when-using-inlineformset)

Remove this reference from the form....

```
qs1 = Vendor.objects.exclude(Q(is_active=False)).distinct()
form.fields['line_item_vendor'].queryset = qs1
```

And instead filter what you want from the get....

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    budget_line_item_form = CreateLineItemFormSet()

    budget_line_item_form.form.base_fields['line_item_vendor'].queryset = \
    Vendor.objects.filter(Q(access_level="Public")
    | Q(access_level="Private",admin_access=user)
    ).exclude(is_active="False")

    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form,
                              line_item_form=line_item_form,
                              context=context,
                              ))
```